How to Generalize Material Planning Algorithm to Handle Multiple Colors in Excel VBA?
I am working on a production planning algorithm in Excel VBA for a rug manufacturing process. My current implementation handles planning for two colors and assigns deficits accordingly (by deficit assigning i mean that everytime a change is made in one of the cells, the difference between of the values will be considered deficit, respectively searching to a cell of the same color to be added up or conquer a empty cell). However, I need to extend the algorithm to handle any number of colors dynamically.
Current Setup: (after edit)

The code detects the row,column and color of the changed cell, it memorizes the difference between the old value and the new value, and this difference becomes a deficit.
The deficit then is assigned to a same colored cell which value is lower than the maximum amount for that process (for example 1200). If there are no cells of the same color that are lower than the max value then:  If the changed cell's row is higher than 7 (exclusively), then we place the deficit in the nearest emptycell, if there are no empty cells before there is encountered a different color, we shift the cells of the different color a cell to the right to make space for the deficit. (row 7 has a different behavior, which i'll figure out how to handle on my own after seeing the ideas for rows 8+)
After assiging the deficit, we will call for the function enough material, the function checks if we have enough material to produce the planned amounts (we know we have enough material, if the sum of the similar colored cells from (currentrow-1)(2) to (currentrow-1)(currentcol-1) is more or equal to the sum of the similar colored cells from (currentrow)(2) to (currentrow)(currentcol). If there is not enough material, we shift the cells to the next cell that has enough material.
The function continues, checking each row and shifting the values.

When I try to extend the algorithm to handle three colors, the enoughMaterial function struggles to manage the material distribution effectively. I want to generalize my code so that it can handle any number of colors without significant performance degradation.
The function in question:
Function enoughMaterial(ByVal startCol As Long, ByVal targetcol As Long, ByVal targetRow As Long, ByVal check As Long)
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Plan") ' Adjust the sheet name as necessary
    Dim lastcol As Long
    Dim lastRow As Long
    lastRow = 17
    lastcol = 53 ' Adjust based on where your data ends
    Dim ok As Long, ok1 As Long
    ok = 0
    ok1 = 0
    Dim VectCol1 As Long, VectCol2 As Long
    Dim VectCol1_1 As Long, VectCol1_2 As Long
    Dim i As Long, j As Long
    Dim i1 As Long, j1 As Long
    Dim color1 As Long, color2 As Long, color As Long
    Dim endRow As Long
    Dim break As Long
    endRow = targetRow
    Dim ok2 As Long
    check = 1
    ok2 = 0
    break = 0
    ' Recalculation of material
    materialC1(1) = 0
    materialC2(1) = 0
    materialV1(1) = 0
    materialV2(1) = 0
    Debug.Print "Starting enoughMaterial with startCol: " & startCol & ", targetcol: " & targetcol & ", targetRow: " & targetRow
    
    If targetRow = 6 Then
        '
        For i2 = startCol To lastcol
            Debug.Print i2
            Debug.Print "MaterialC: " & materialC(i2) & " " & "MaterialV: " & materialV(i2)
        Next i2
        '
        Debug.Print "Processing row 6"
        For i1 = endRow To endRow
            For j1 = startCol To lastcol
                If j1 = startCol Then
                    materialC(j1) = ws.Cells(i1, j1).Value
                    materialV(j1) = ws.Cells(i1 + 1, j1).Value
                Else
                    materialC(j1) = materialC(j1 - 1) + ws.Cells(i1, j1).Value
                    materialV(j1) = materialV(j1 - 1) + ws.Cells(i1 + 1, j1).Value
                End If
                Debug.Print "Row: " & i1 & ", Col: " & j1 & ", materialC: " & materialC(j1) & ", materialV: " & materialV(j1)
            If materialC(j1 - 1) - materialV(j1) < 0 And ok2 = 0 Then
                break = j1
                ok2 = 1
            End If
            Next j1
        Next i1
    Debug.Print break & " " & targetcol
    
        If break <> 0 Then
            targetcol = break
            If targetcol Mod 2 = 0 Then
                targetcol = targetcol + 1
            End If
        Debug.Print endRow
        Debug.Print targetcol & " "; endRow; " " & targetcol - 2
        For i = endRow To endRow
            For j = targetcol To lastcol Step 2
                materialPos = materialC(j - 2) - materialV(j)
                Debug.Print "Checking material position for row 6 at col: " & j & ", materialPos: " & materialPos

                If materialPos >= 0 Then
                    ' It has enough material, so we skip
                Else
                    ' Day shift color
                    color1 = ws.Cells(i + 1, j - 1).Interior.color
                    color2 = ws.Cells(i + 1, j).Interior.color
                    ' Night shift color
                    

                   Debug.Print "Color1: " & color1 & ", Color2: " & color2
                    Debug.Print "Day value: " & ws.Cells(i + 1, j - 1).Value & ", Night value: " & ws.Cells(i + 1, j).Value

                    ShiftCells endRow + 1, j, color1, color2, ws.Cells(i + 1, j - 1), ws.Cells(i + 1, j), ok
                End If
            Next j
        Next i
        End If
    ElseIf targetRow <= 15 Then
        For i2 = startCol To lastcol
            Debug.Print i2
            Debug.Print "MaterialC1: " & materialC1(i2) & " " & "MaterialV1: " & materialV1(i2)
            Debug.Print "MaterialC2: " & materialC2(i2) & " " & "MaterialV2: " & materialV2(i2)
        Next i2
        
        Debug.Print "Processing row <= 14"
        'Pentru formarea materialului prezent in dependenta de zi
        For i1 = endRow To endRow
            For j1 = startCol To lastcol
                currentcolor = ws.Cells(i1, j1).Interior.color
                If ok = 0 And ws.Cells(i1, j1).Value <> 0 Then
                    ok = 1
                    VectCol1 = currentcolor
                    For t = 1 To k
                    materialC1(j1) = materialC1(j1 - 1) + ws.Cells(i1, j1).Value
                    materialC2(j1) = materialC2(j1 - 1)
                ElseIf currentcolor = VectCol1 Then
                    materialC1(j1) = materialC1(j1 - 1) + ws.Cells(i1, j1).Value
                    materialC2(j1) = materialC2(j1 - 1)
                ElseIf currentcolor <> VectCol1 And ok1 = 0 And ws.Cells(i1, j1).Value <> 0 Then
                    ok1 = 1
                    VectCol2 = currentcolor
                    materialC2(j1) = materialC2(j1 - 1) + ws.Cells(i1, j1).Value
                    materialC1(j1) = materialC1(j1 - 1)
                ElseIf currentcolor = VectCol2 Then
                    materialC2(j1) = materialC2(j1 - 1) + ws.Cells(i1, j1).Value
                    materialC1(j1) = materialC1(j1 - 1)
                Else
                    materialC1(j1) = materialC1(j1 - 1)
                    materialC2(j1) = materialC2(j1 - 1)
                End If
                'Debug.Print "Row: " & i1 & ", Col: " & j1 & ", currentcolor: " & currentcolor & ", materialC1: " & materialC1(j1) & ", materialC2: " & materialC2(j1)
            Next j1
        Next i1
        ok = 0
        ok1 = 0
        'pentru materialului cheltuit pana in ziua de azi
        ok2 = 0
        break = targetcol
        For j1 = startCol To lastcol
            currentcolor = ws.Cells(i1, j1).Interior.color
            If ok = 0 And ws.Cells(i1, j1).Value <> 0 Then
                ok = 1
                VectCol1_1 = currentcolor
                materialV1(j1) = materialV1(j1 - 1) + ws.Cells(i1, j1).Value
                materialV2(j1) = materialV2(j1 - 1)
            ElseIf currentcolor = VectCol1_1 Then
                materialV1(j1) = materialV1(j1 - 1) + ws.Cells(i1, j1).Value
                materialV2(j1) = materialV2(j1 - 1)
            ElseIf currentcolor <> VectCol1_1 And ok1 = 0 And ws.Cells(i1, j1).Value <> 0 Then
                ok1 = 1
                VectCol1_2 = currentcolor
                materialV2(j1) = materialV2(j1 - 1) + ws.Cells(i1, j1).Value
                materialV1(j1) = materialV1(j1 - 1)
            ElseIf currentcolor = VectCol1_2 Then
                materialV2(j1) = materialV2(j1 - 1) + ws.Cells(i1, j1).Value
                materialV1(j1) = materialV1(j1 - 1)
            Else
                materialV1(j1) = materialV1(j1 - 1)
                materialV2(j1) = materialV2(j1 - 1)
            End If
            'Debug.Print "Row: " & i1 & ", Col: " & j1 & ", currentcolor: " & currentcolor & ", materialV1: " & materialV1(j1) & ", materialV2: " & materialV2(j1)
            If (materialC1(j1 - 1) - materialV1(j1) < 0 Or materialC2(j1 - 1) - materialV2(j1) < 0) And ok2 = 0 Then
                break = j1
                ok2 = 1
            End If
        Next j1
        'materialpos1 e pentru material posibil pentru culoarea 1, si deja materialpos2 pentru a 2-a
        For i = endRow To endRow
            For j = break To lastcol
                materialPos1 = materialC1(j - 1) - materialV1(j)
                'Debug.Print "materialPos1 at Row: " & i & ", Col: " & j & " = " & materialPos1
                materialPos2 = materialC2(j - 1) - materialV2(j)
                'Debug.Print "materialPos2 at Row: " & i & ", Col: " & j & " = " & materialPos2

                If materialPos1 >= 0 And materialPos2 >= 0 Then
                    'skip
                Else
                    If materialPos1 < 0 Then
                        color = ws.Cells(i + 1, j).Interior.color
                        Debug.Print "ShiftCells call with color: " & color & ", materialPos1: " & materialPos1
                        Call ShiftCells(endRow + 1, j, color, RGB(255, 255, 255), ws.Cells(i + 1, j), 0, 1)
                    End If
                    If materialPos2 < 0 Then
                        color = ws.Cells(i + 1, j).Interior.color
                        Debug.Print "ShiftCells call with color: " & color & ", materialPos2: " & materialPos2
                        Call ShiftCells(endRow + 1, j, color, RGB(255, 255, 255), ws.Cells(i + 1, j), 0, 2)
                    End If
                    check = 0
                End If
            Next j
        Next i
    End If
    Debug.Print endRow
    If endRow > 17 Then
        'skip
    Else
        Debug.Print "Recursing with startCol: 2, targetcol: " & targetcol + 1 & ", endRow: " & endRow + 1
        enoughMaterial 2, targetcol + 1, endRow + 1, check
    End If
End Function

For reference this function is called after assigning a deficit from a certain color (it is not optimal, i know)
The table i'm working on:

(The table can be extended for multiple weeks)
Request:
Could someone help me refactor my enoughMaterial function or provide a generalized approach to handle multiple colors dynamically in Excel VBA? Detailed suggestions or code snippets would be highly appreciated.
The current approach involves hardcoding checks and loops for two colors, which is not scalable. I considered the following potential solutions but faced some challenges:
-Adding more checks and loops for additional colors (inefficient and not scalable).
-Using dictionaries or lists to manage colors dynamically (seems promising but unsure how to implement efficiently, besides, this option was suggested by GPT-4, so i have no idea how to implement it or what it does).

The question would be better if you start with describing the planning algorithm.

@ErwinKalvelagen I explained the planning algorithm in the edit

This is not a complete answer to your question, since I'm having trouble following your code/algorithm. However, below is an example of how to create a "list" of colors in your range.
A few things to specifically note:

Your code has problems - at the least, your t loop variable is never used and the loop is not terminated with next t. We can't run your algorithm and it makes it difficult to understand.
Please use Option Explicit in all your code. Many of your variables are defined outside of the function in your post - this makes it difficult to copy into a local spreadsheet to test for us.
Add a reference to the Microsoft Scripting Runtime to get access to the Dictionary.
Try to use variable names that are more descriptive. It helps to understand your code a bit better. This is partly why I have trouble following your algorithm.

Option Explicit

Sub test()
    With Sheet1
        Dim notTheseColors As Variant
        ReDim notTheseColors(1)
        notTheseColors(0) = CStr(.Range("A1").Interior.color) 'exclude the default background color
        notTheseColors(1) = CStr(.Range("L4").Interior.color) 'exclude the weekend color
        
        '--- define the area with the data
        Dim lastcol As Long
        Dim lastRow As Long
        lastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
        lastcol = .Cells(2, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
        
        Dim dataArea As Range
        Set dataArea = .Range(.Cells(5, 2), .Cells(lastRow, lastcol))
        
        Dim allColors As Dictionary
        Set allColors = FindAllColors(dataArea, notTheseColors)
                                      
        '--- now use this Dictionary in your loops to check the
        '    color-coded values in your data range, possibly like
        '    this:
        Debug.Print "Processing row <= 14"
        'Pentru formarea materialului prezent in dependenta de zi
        
        
        
        '--- THIS ALGORITHM IS WRONG!!! this is more of a guide
        '    than actual working code!!!
        Dim currentWorkingColor As Variant
        For Each currentWorkingColor In allColors
            '--- work by columns
            Dim r As Long
            For r = 1 To dataArea.Rows.Count
                Dim c As Long
                For c = 1 To dataArea.Columns.Count
                    Dim thisCellColor As String
                    thisCellColor = CStr(ws.Cells(i1, j1).Interior.color) 'note the conversion to String
                
                    If thisCellColor = currentWorkingColor Then
                        materialC1(j1) = materialC1(j1 - 1) + ws.Cells(i1, j1).Value
                        materialC2(j1) = materialC2(j1 - 1)
                    Else
                        materialC1(j1) = materialC1(j1 - 1)
                        materialC2(j1) = materialC2(j1 - 1)
                    End If
                Next c
            Next r
            '--- work by rows
            Dim r As Long
            For r = 1 To dataArea.Rows.Count
                Dim c As Long
                For c = 1 To dataArea.Columns.Count
                    Dim thisCellColor As String
                    thisCellColor = CStr(ws.Cells(i1, j1).Interior.color) 'note the conversion to String
                
                    If thisCellColor = currentWorkingColor Then
                        materialV1(j1) = materialV1(j1 - 1) + ws.Cells(i1, j1).Value
                        materialV2(j1) = materialV2(j1 - 1)
                    Else
                        materialV1(j1) = materialV1(j1 - 1)
                        materialV2(j1) = materialV2(j1 - 1)
                    End If
                Next c
            Next r
        Next currentWorkingColor
    End With
End Sub

Function FindAllColors(ByRef thisArea As Range, _
                       ByRef excludedColors As Variant) As Dictionary
    '--- given a range of cells, create a list of all
    '    existing colors in those cells
    Dim colors As Dictionary
    Set colors = New Dictionary
    
    Dim entry As Range
    For Each entry In thisArea
        Dim entryColor As String
        entryColor = CStr(entry.Interior.color)
        If Not IsInList(excludedColors, entryColor) Then
            If Not colors.Exists(entryColor) Then
                '--- this color does not exist in the given range, so
                '    create a dictionary item using color (as a STRING)
                '    as the dictionary key, with a value of one to start
                colors.Add entryColor, 1
            Else
                '--- the color already exists, so just add to the count
                '
                '*** you may not need to count the number of cells with
                '    this color at this point. if you don't need the count,
                '    then you can skip this "else" part of the code
                colors(entryColor) = colors(entryColor) + 1
            End If
        End If
    Next entry
    Set FindAllColors = colors
End Function

Function IsInList(ByRef theList As Variant, ByVal checkValue As String) As Boolean
    IsInList = Not (IsError(Application.Match(checkValue, theList, 0)))
End Function

